# Reuse recipe in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to reuse same recipe multiple times. For example I have a recipe to install certificate on Windows machine (download it, put in in proper store, ...). But depends on machine/role I would like to run it only for X certificates.

I am using full chef infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef two another concepts that fit this task better than recipes do:

- [Definititons](http://docs.chef.io/definitions.html): Allows you to combine multiple resources (`remote_file`, `execute`, etc) to one new resource. Probably the right thing for you.
- [Libraries](http://docs.chef.io/libraries.html): Are plain ruby code and fit fore more complex tasks.

As suggested by Sebastian, you can still iterate over a data bag in a recipe. Although this is true, the cleaner way to group the tasks *download it, put in in proper store, ...* would be a definition or library.

Comment: Definitions are exactly what I was looking for.